# Given a unit circle, is there a diameter that intersect it in one single point?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

This is false but this is what I have come up with:

The circle can be written as $x=\cos\phi$, $y=\sin\phi$, $\phi \in \left [ 0,2\pi  \right ]$

Denote now $t=\tan{\frac{\phi}{2}}$ and it follows that $x=\cos\phi=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$ and $y=\sin\phi=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$.

Consider now the diameter that lies on the $x$-axis; It will be given for $y=0$ and thus $t=0$. But $t=0$ gives only $x=1$, thus we have found a diameter that intersect the circle in one single point.

Comment: You mean "the **unit** circle", right?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: You might want the range of $\phi$ to be $[0,2\pi)$ so you don't cover $(1,0)$ twice.  I think you don't want $t=\tan \frac t 2$

Comment: This question is similar to Stereographic projection.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To describe all points of the circle, you must allow $t=\infty$ (for the point $x=-1, y=0$) with the usual harmful implications on arithmetic. If you do so, "$y=0$ and thus $t=0$" is a *non sequitur*.